# 301 Redirect Module works randomly with languages

Tags: redirect

We are using this 301 Redirect Module: https://github.com/thecadams/301RedirectModule

We have an issue where we are redirecting with the language identifier in place in the URL to a URL that does not have the language identifier. Example below:

- /ja-jp/dogs/pit-bulls/blue-nose-pit-bull to /dogs/pit-bulls/blue-nose-pit-bull

With other languages such as /en/ or /es/ the redirect works. However, it is not redirecting for Japan language identifier. Is this a known issue or has anyone seen this in the past that can help to resolve this issue or provide a better alternative?

Comment: In your example, are you saying that you want the page to be in the Japanese language context, and that you want to strip the URL of the `/ja-jp` portion?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely correct Marcel.